# How to hide li if ul has no have li with class using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Im trying to hide li if has no have li

Here html :

```
  <li>
   <a href="#" class="">My Profile</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="https://tap.local:9991/profile" class="">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://tap.local:9991/profile/edit" class="">Edit Profile</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="#">Menu must be hide</a>
   <ul>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all the `ul` iterate through them to get the content and if no conetent is available then use parentNode to get the parent li and add class to the parent to hide it

```js
const allULs = document.querySelectorAll("ul");
allULs.forEach(function(a) {
   0 === a.innerHTML.trim().length && 
   a.parentElement.classList.add("hideParent");
});
```

```css
.hideParent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="#" class="">My Profile</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://tap.local:9991/profile" class="">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://tap.local:9991/profile/edit" class="">Edit Profile</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Menu must be hide</a>
  <ul>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: you can use `.hide()` to element in JQuery. not need to add class